# Office 365 migration PST

Tags: migration, outlook, office365

I can't migrate from Outlook to Office 365. In fact , I can't get into the cloud. My version of 365 is E1

It tells me that I am not authorized to identify myself on Azure while it is my admin account.

I am not added as an external user at the level of Tenant in AzureAD. What do you think about that ? Have you seen this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

In Office 365, Global Admins are the only role with access to all administrative features. A Global Admin will typically be the person who signs up to purchase Office 365. Your company can also have more than one Global Admin.

Grant Global Admin rights to an Office 365 user by logging into https://portal.office.com with an admin account and go to the "Admin" section.You can now either create a new account to delegate Global Admin rights to, or delegate admin access to an existing user.